# Storing values in struct objects using c and a do-while loop

Tags: c

I'm trying to store a few values in a struct object and I want to repeat the prompt until the user types in "yes". I want to use a do-while loop for that. I'm already failing with the read-in of the first "last name". When I type in something, the program just stops (no error). I don't even use the do-while, since I'm not sure if it will work with my while() condition.

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

struct employeelist 
{
 char last[6];
 char first[6];
 int pnumber;
 int salary;
};

int main()

{
 struct employeelist employee[5]; 
 char check; 

 //do
 //{
 printf("Hello. Please type in the last name, the first name, the personal number and the salary of your employees.\n");
 printf("Last name: ");
 scanf("%c", employee[1].last);  

 printf("First name: ");
 scanf("%c", employee[1].first);  

 printf("Personal number: ");
 scanf("%d", &employee[1].pnumber);  

 printf("Salary: ");
 scanf("%d", &employee[1].salary);  

 printf("You have more employess (yes/no)?: ");
 scanf("%c", &check);  
 //}while (scanf("yes"));

 return 0;
}
```

Comment: You do realize you didn't actually ask a question, right?  You dumped a bunch of code and said, "it doesn't work".

Comment: Sorry, i will try to be more specific the next time. And this is no homework i'm doing for school, i'm just learning for myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `%s` as your format specifier if you're trying to get a string. You might also want to limit its length to 5, since that's how much space you have for `last` and `first`. So that would be `%5s`. Also, 5 characters is pretty short for a name.

Another comment: arrays in C are zero-based, so `employee[1]` is the second `employeelist` in your array. If you want to do this in a loop with an incrementing index, start at 0.

Comment: Thank you! Is it necessary to give a value for the char [length]?

Comment: @Ordo: Sort of. If you want to dynamically allocate space for the string at run-time, there's a GNU extension that lets you use 'a' in the conversion specifier to have `scanf` call `malloc`. Of course, that probably won't work in Microsoft's C++ compiler. You can also call malloc yourself, but for homework it's probably easiest to just allocate large buffers statically and hold your users to it with the format specifier.

Comment: If you want to store it in a character array, then you have to specify the length unless you plan on mallocing one

Answer (score 1):

Hi when you read char array you must use scanf("%s", employee[1].last);  %s but not %c

Answer (score 1):

What do you think this code does?

```
scanf("%c", ....
```

`%c` indicates that scanf should only read **ONE** character.
One letter is not going to get you an entire name.

You need to switch to `%s` for starters.

Answer (score 1):

1. First of all the first index to work
   with will be '0',not 1.
2. wrong identifier for string,it
   should be %s.
3. If you just want to iterate by
   asking y/n then just change the
   display message from yes/no to y/n
   and also change that strange while
   condition to check=='y'||check=='Y'.
4. The code will actually not work
   after 5 iterations because you
   initialized only 5 structures of
   that type.Why don't you add that in
   the loop?